# Inaccurate (non-smooth) boundary of the mesh generated by ToElementMesh

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I try to generate a mesh over a region, which has a wavy boundary at its bottom and needs very fine mesh around the bottom.

However, the generated mesh boundary is not as smooth as the specified one. The region is 
[image]
The generated mesh is
[image]
If we zone-in we will find the bottom boundary is not 
[image]

The bottom looks very bad.

I further try to generate the boundary first. Here is what I found.
[image]

The boundary is not generated correctly.

Anyone know how to generate the correct meshed boundary?

---

I have got the answer from http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1221340?sortMsg=Votes:

### **Adding a range of {{x,-0.6,0.6},{y,0,0.3}} in defining the region.**

The minimum work code is as follows.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

width = 1;
heigth = 0.25;
radius = 10; 
ydatum = 0.006;
Aw = 2 10^-3;
λw = 0.1;
ℛ = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Abs[x] <= width/2 && y <= heigth + ydatum && 
    y >= x^2/(2 radius) + Aw (1 - Cos[(2 π x)/λw]) + 
      ydatum, {{x,-0.6,0.6},{y,0,0.3}}];
RegionPlot[ℛ, FrameTicks -> None, PlotPoints -> 20000,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.48, 0.48}, {0.005, 0.256}}]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ℛ, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation", AccuracyGoal -> 2]
bmesh["Wireframe"]

meshrefine = 
  Function[{vertices, area}, 
   Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
    If[ydatum < y < ydatum + 0.01, area > 2.1*10^-7, area > 0.001]]];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[ℛ, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> meshrefine]

mesh1["Wireframe"]

Show[mesh1["Wireframe"], 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.025, 0.025}, {0.005, 0.02}}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: Weird. I do not know why this happens. In my opinion, this is not the expected behavior and you should consider filing a bug report at Wolfram support. For the moment, I can get it working by adding the option `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0002` to the call to `ToElementMesh`: This adds only a few thousand triangles but the boundary seems to be discretized accurately.

Comment: Thank you. The option MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0002 works for me. Maybe because the mesh size has a large gradient in my original case?

Comment: You're welcome. I also thought so. Maybe using a smoother `MeshRefinementFunction` will also help.

Comment: Could you please clarify how to using a smoother MeshRefinementFunction? The same problem happens if I increase the amplitude of the wavy boundary, although I played around with changing the value of MaxCellMeasure. See the updated post.

Comment: The `MeshRefinementFunction` you use has discontinuities in `y = ydatum + 0.01` and `y = ydatum` This causes that several triangles that are adjacent to each other are treated completely different. If I were a meshing algorithm, I wouldn't like to get such inputs/

Answer (score 9):

If you use a better refinement function things works as expected:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   Abs[x] <= width/2 && y <= heigth + ydatum && 
    y >= x^2/(2 radius) + Aw (1 - Cos[(2 π x)/λw]) + 
      ydatum, {x, y}];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[reg, "MeshOrder" -> 1,
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.0005 Mean[vertices[[All, 2]]]]];
mesh1["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not quite understand how the refine mesh function works. For example, what does Mean[vertices[[All, 2]]] mean? There is a computation balance in my case since I need to cut down the computation time. Hence I need a very fine meh at the bottom, but not at the rest part, e.g., say the mesh size (MaxCellMeasure->{"Length"->0.001/3}) at the bottom is about 0.001/3, but the mesh size at the rest part can be larger. At the same time, I want to generate the mesh as a gradient change of mesh size as you did (instead of a abrupt change of mesh size in my post).

Comment: @Wilhelm have a look at the documentation. Look for `MeshRefinementFunction` and in the options of `ToElementMesh` to see examples.

Comment: Thank you @user21.