# Very bad mesh when using MeshRefinementFunction

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

This post is not a duplication of [another post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159775/inaccurate-non-smooth-boundary-of-the-mesh-generated-by-toelementmesh), which is a region plot problem. Basically, the problem shown here is caused by a curved boundary, which is belong to the region aimed to be refined, and the mesh refinement function.

I try to generate a mesh with an extremely refined region. The generate mesh is good, when the parameter $Aw$ is small (e.g., $Aw<0.4$) . But it has very bad quality when  $Aw$ is large.

```
width = 5.0;
height = 1.25;
radius = 10; 
ydatum = 0.006;
Aw = 0.8*10^-3;
λw = 0.1;
ℛ = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= width/2 && y <= height + ydatum && 
    y >= Aw (1 - Cos[(2 π x)/λw]) + ydatum + x^2/(
      2 radius), {{x, 0 - 0.1, width/2 + 0.1}, {y, 0, height + 0.1}}];

meshrefine = Function[{vertices, area},
   Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices];
    y0 = x^2/(2 radius) + Aw (1 - Cos[(2 π x)/λw]) + 
  ydatum;
    y1 = x^2/(2 radius*3) + Aw (1 - Cos[(2 π x)/λw]) + 
  ydatum + 0.007;
    y2 = 0.05;
    y3 = 0.1;
    If[y0 <= y <= y1, area > 2.5 10^-7, 
     If[y1 < y <= y2, area > 5 10^-6, 
      If[y2 < y <= y3, area > 2 10^-5, area > 10^-3]]]
    ]
   ];

mesh1 = ToElementMesh[ℛ, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, MeshRefinementFunction -> meshrefine]
Show[meshIn["Wireframe"], ImageSize -> Full]
Show[meshIn["Wireframe"], ImageSize -> 1800, 
 PlotRange -> {{0., 0.2}, {0, 0.05}}]
```

The generated mesh is as follow:
[image]

However, if we examine the bottom curved boundary, we will find that the boundary is not smooth but with sawtooth irregularities, for example,
[image]

Anyone know how to fix this problem to get exact boundary mesh? Even put forward a new mesh refinement function instead of the current one, to get the desired mesh as shown in the first figure.

Comment: Add a option "AccuracyGoal->5" in the ToElementMesh function.